# Calculus of Curves - Advanced Calc

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given a curve $s(t)$, show that if $a$ = $c$ (so acceleration is constant) then $v(t) \times a(t)$ is constant. $v(t)$ is the derivative of $s(t)$ and $a(t)$ is the derivative of $v(t)$.

I understand that since $a$ is constant crossing the velocity function and the acceleration function would give us a non-zero vector. Certainly the speed would be increasing at a constant rate, but I don't know how that would fit in to the problem. Any help or clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try showing that $v(t)=ct+D$ for some constant, $D$, and then just compute $v(t) \times a(t)$.

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean that $a(t)=c$ (a constant vector), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try differentiating the cross-product.
The general formula is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{u})
 = \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} \times \mathbf{u}
    + \mathbf{v} \times \frac{d\mathbf{u}}{dt}.
$$
For your particular question, set $\mathbf{v} = v(t)$ and $\mathbf{u} = a(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given acceleration the constant vector (I am assuming vectors since I think you mean the cross product and you have a multivariable tag), then we have
$$
\vec{a(t)}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)
$$
Which implies that $\vec{v(t)}$ is
$$
\vec{v(t)}=\int(a_1,a_2,a_3)dt=(a_1t,a_2t,a_3t)+\vec{c}
$$
Then just compute the cross product
$$
(a_1,a_2,a_3)\times(a_1t+c_1,a_2t+c_2,a_3t+c_3)=(a_2a_3t-a_3a_2t+a_2c_3-a_3c_2,-(c_1c_3t-c_3c_1t+a_1c_3-a_3c_1),c_1c_2t-c_2c_1t+a_1c_2-a_2c_1)\\
=(a_2c_3-a_3c_2,a_3c_1-a_1c_3,a_1c_2-a_2c_1)
$$
A constant vector.